# Storyboard buttons are off-kilter

Tags: ios, swift, interface

XCode 9.3: macOS 10.13.4

I have an swift app where the buttons are off-kilter. I need them at the bottom of the screen and centered. The iOS simulator for iPhone 8 shows the buttons correctly. However, the simulator for the iPhone SE and the actual SE (my iPhone) show the buttons anchored to the right edge of the screen. How can I insure that the buttons are displayed correctly on all iPhones?

[image: storyboard]

[image: iPhone SE simulator]

Comment: I'd put the buttons in a UIStackView that is anchored to the center, bottom, left, and right of the parent view.

Comment: have you added constraints for the stack view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First sol**

this layout can be done correctly if the center of the middle button is equal to the center of the screen

**Second sol**

create a `UIStackView` with these constraints

1- left , right , bottom to screen

2- height say 100

with distribution set to `fillEqually` , spacing set to say 20

drag the buttons inside it and they will look right in any device

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the constraints from the 3 buttons: Calc, Clear, and Help
- Align clear to be horizontally centered
- Align Calc trailing offset from Clear's leading.
- Align Helps Leading offset from Clear's trailing.
- Align Clear bottom offset from the bottom margin.
- Align Clear, Calc, and Help along to center vertically with one another.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: 1) use the legacy struts and springs mode in interface builder to distribute your items as you need them or 2) spend the time learning auto layout, and use it instead.  There isn't any easy answer because of all the different screen sizes, and you haven't even considered iPad screens here.  The best way to pick  up auto layout is to view the WWDC videos on the subject.  Yes, it will take longer, but your app will respond better to screen changes, and you will also be able to inherently accommodate new screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a horizontal stack view for buttons, and set spacing between buttons.

> Approach 1 - Set trailing space and leading space, pin the view to bottom and set a fixed height for stack view.
>
> Approach 2 -
> Set fixed height and width to stack view and center horizontally, and pin the stack view to bottom.

Always try to use stack view, with that you will reduce the number of autolayout issues you run into.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add the constraint for stack view and adjust like that:**

[image]